# list to either of list

Tags: haskell, exception

Say I have the following parser function:

```
validateA :: MyMonad m => TypeA -> TypeB
validateA a = (fmapLT Service $ getB $ bId a) >>= \bResult ->
  case bResult of
    Nothing -> throwError $ Validation InvalidBId
    Just actualB -> return $ B actualB
```

Where `getB` makes an http request to another service

And I wish to map that across an array like so:

```
validateAs
  :: MyMonad m
  => [TypeA]
  -> ExceptT Error m [TypeB]

validateAs as = map validateA as
```

This fails to compile with:

```
    • Couldn't match type ‘[]’ with ‘ExceptT Error m’
      Expected type: ExceptT Error m [TypeB]
        Actual type: [ExceptT Error m0 TypeB]
    • In the expression: map validateA as
      In an equation for ‘validateAs’:
          validateAs as = map validateA as
    • Relevant bindings include
        validateAs :: [TypeA]
                             -> ExceptT Error m [TypeB]
          (bound at lib/Flock/Policies/Core/Domain/CancelPolicyV2/Validation.hs:89:1)
   |
89 | validateAs as = map validateAs as
```

How can I map across a list where every call could fail, but then lift the exception out like i want?

Basically how do I go from:

```
v :: m => A -> ExceptT Error B
```

and

```
[A]
```

to

```
ExceptT Error [B]
```

Comment: But your function `validateA` has type `TypeA -> TypeB` and can't call error situation. Maybe you keep in mind type `TypeA -> ExceptT Error m TypeB`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map` has type `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`, so you get `[ExceptT Error m0 TypeB]` instead of `ExceptT Error m [TypeB]`. You can apply `sequenceA` to your result:

```hs
validateSchedules as = sequenceA $ map validateA as
```

You can also use function `traverse` for this:

```hs
validateSchedules as = traverse validateA as
```

Comment: `traverse` on lists was formally known as `mapM`, the monadic version of map.  (But that is archaic vocabulary since `Traversable`)